# Книги на русском языке

Tags: книги

Всем доброго времени суток. Будучи программистом, нередко читаю различную профильную литературу. Подавляющее большинство этих книг написано зарубежными авторами - от признанных классиков вроде Фаулера до гораздо менее известных авторов. Честно говоря, не припомню ни одной по-настоящему хорошей книги, что я читал, написанной российскими авторами. Есть ли вообще достойная литература от отечественного производителя,как вы считаете?

Comment: По теории алгоритмов есть серьёзные работы, но именно практическое современное программирование у нас вроде бы не было настолько развито 20 лет назад в силу многих причин -- то есть и наших книг по нему быть не должно. А впрочем, может быть кто-то и вспомнит.

Comment: Кто нибудь знает хоть один широко распространенный компилятор/интерпретатор/виртуальную машину от русских разработчиков? Мне на ум приходит разве что 1С и компиляторы для мелкосерийных советских процессоров  и то там скорее всего не оригинальный язык а простой С взят за основу.  Нет компиляторов нет и литературы. Как в старом анекдоте про ребенка инвалида, его папашу и мультики. Нет ног сынок, нет мультиков.

Comment: @igumnov: Мне кажется, отсутствие компиляторов и отсутствие книг -- следствия одной и той же причины.

Comment: @igumnov до копирования западной техники были. После -- было уже не до того.
Хотя... mosml -- лёгкая реализация sml97

Comment: @VladD Хороший учебник по ЯП высокого уровня может написать только человек непосредственно придумавший его и разработавший первый компилятор. Вся остальная литература от остальных авторов в лучшем случае будет по качеству равна оригиналу. В реальности же образуются стопка бестолковых мануалов вроде "C++ с нуля за 30 дней" В.Пупкин Издательство "Рога и копыта" за которые еще вдобавок просят заплатить.

Comment: @igumnov, не согласен.

Comment: Кстати, такая ситуация не только в информатике. Например, по современной биологии, по математике, по химии хороших отечественных учебников (написанных глубоко но понятно и доступно) тоже очень и очень мало.

Comment: @igumnov: Ну, например по C++ есть неплохие на мой вкус книги и не только авторства Страуструпа. (Хотя, считать ли C++ языком высокого или среднего уровня не так уж и очевидно.)

Comment: @mikillskegg боюсь, это  всё оттого, что практически вся наша академическая наука находится в глубокой ж...эммм...стагнации

Comment: >Хороший учебник по ЯП высокого уровня может написать только человек непосредственно придумавший его и разработавший первый компилятор

не соглашусь. Во-первых, есть множество примеров, когда отличные книги писались вовсе не авторами языка, а во-вторых, если человек способен разработать язык, еще не означает, что он способен написать хорошую книгу - на это тоже талант нужен, которого у разработчика языка/компилятора может не оказаться

Comment: @Dreamchild, эта ситуация наблюдалась и 20, и 30 лет назад, когда наука была совсем еще не там. Конечно, есть исключения, но очень мало.

Comment: @mikillskegg 30 лет назад это наблюдалось по другой причине - тогда программирование (а ранее кибернетика) было у нас в ранге лженауки. А вот по прочим дисциплинам все же выпускалось немало достойных книг

Comment: @DreamChild Вы считать умеете? 30 лет назад -- 1983 г. Уже не только Ряд-1, но и Ряд-2 (в девичестве S/370), СМ-3/СМ-4 -- (в девичестве pdp11/40) и некоторые другие. Лженаука...

А 40 лет назад -- БЭСМ-6, Минск-32, М-222...

Comment: А интересный вопрос. 

Лично я могу припомнить только одну интересную книжку. 

Точно названия не помню, что-то вроде "Язык СЕТЛ и его реализация на БЭСМ-6", автор Левин (кажется он в 70-е, 80-е работал в ВЦ АН в Новосибирске).

Comment: Товарищ, окончивший НГУ, рассказывал про одного новосибирского затейника. Случайно сталкивался с кем-нибудь по дороге и рассыпал колоду перфокарт (вероятно на Basic). Лихорадочно собирал, на извинения реагировал -- "Да всё нормально, всё в порядке". Затем -- пари, что всё в порядке, запуск колоды на трансляцию/выполнение, получение результата, выигрыш пари (Для тех, кто не помнит -- в Basic номер оператора был обязателен и порядок карт значения не имел).

Comment: @alexlz любезнейший, не придирайтесь к словам. Я умею считать (во всяком случае до тридцати) и более-менее осведомлен об истории развития программирования, хотя и крайне рад, что вы блещете такими познаниями. Я, может, не совсем точно выразился, но я имел в виду, что сейчас отечественная наука находится в заднице, а в то время, когда она там еще не находилась, приоритеты были несколько иными

Comment: @DreamChild Да я не хотел придираться. Просто это уже после великого поворота (массового копирования американской техники ради американского программного обеспечения). А начало развития программирования в СССР -- это 50е-60е годы (когда компьютеры были большими, а их производительность -- маленькой).
А насчёт науки в заднице, когда и как -- то это вопрос сложный и спорный. У решения о копировании были серьёзные основания.

Comment: @DreamChild, а тут ведь вопрос несколько сместился. Дело в том, что и во времена, когда

    приоритеты были несколько иными

книг наших авторов, написанных действительно интересно и  *живым языком* практически не было. А вот куча формализма часто присутствовала.

Вот какими традициями это можно объяснить?

Comment: @VladD, 

    тогда программирование было в основном академической дисциплиной

это сильно спорное утверждение. Практически в каждом НИИ был ВЦ (и на многих заводах тоже) и всюду работали программисты, которые что-нибудь писали.

Comment: @avp: тогда программирование было в основном академической дисциплиной, и книги/статьи писались так, как принято в академической среде. Сейчас же в программировании "живые" люди, им больше подходят книги, написанные живым языком. (Ну и не забывайте, многие хорошие учёные крайне интровертны, они физически не могут писать по другому.)

---
Хм, наверное, вы правы. Но всё же сейчас программирование гораздо более массовая профессия.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть, вот например [Алгоритмы: Построение, анализ и реализация на языке программирования Си Ворожцов А. В., Винокуров Н. А.](http://forcoder.ru/algorithm/algoritmy-postroenie-analiz-i-realizaciya-na-yazyke-programmirovaniya-si-719)  потрясающий учебник. В бумажном варианте [двухтомник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5039922/).

Comment: @Merlin, а я после характеристики  "потрясающий учебник" его сейчас (с 3-й попытки) скачал (в pdf) и пару часов посмотрел. 

Возможно я сильно недооцениваю интеллект студентов Физтеха, но мне кажется, что некоторые вещи (на самом деле их наверняка больше)  рассмотрены на поверхностном уровне.

Адресация элементов многомерных массивов.

Выбор разделяющего элемента в quicksort.

(про устойчивость сортировок вообще ни слова)

Удаление из хэш-таблицы с открытой адресацией.

Программирование RB дерева (в отличие от АВЛ).

...


Тут уже места мало для остального. IMHO оценка книги ~4.

Comment: на уровне вполне достаточном для того, чтобы начать программировать, а не "кодить". Не думаю, что есть книга, в которой описаны **всё**, подробно, с обоснованием и примерами. А хотя есть такая книга, называется [Google][1].


  [1]: http://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=профессиональное+программирование&oq=профессиональное+програм&gs_l=hp.3.0.0l4.29955.37119.3.37701.24.22.0.2.2.1.1296.4706.4j11j5j1j7-1.22.0...0.0...1c.1.2.hp.WKPXwsdrfDI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.bGE&fp=d4ccac94b4ae016c&biw=1484&bih=968

Answer (score 4):

Есть Котеров и книги по php...
Есть И.Кантор(или Кантер) и его ресурс javascript.ru - отличнейший учебник.
Есть В.Моржевич и его ресурс htmlbook.ru - опять же отличный учебник.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно есть. Было бы странно, если бы не было.

Вообще, скорее всего, пропорции в англоязычной и русскоязычной литературе одинаковы, просто о плохих зарубежных книгах мы не узнаём. Да и переводят только то, что как минимум, заслуживает внимания.

---

Пример русскоязычной книги:

> Паттерны проектирования на платформе .NET
>   Тепляков С. В.
>
> Тема: Вне серии
>   Год: 2016
>   Страниц: 320
>   Обложка: Обл Ц
>   Формат: 70х100/16
>   Баркод: 9785496016490
>   ISBN: 978-5-496-01649-0

http://habrahabr.ru/company/piter/blog/257721/
http://www.piter.com/product?product_id=39684273